# (Angular2/primeng) Datatable mouseover repeating rendering

Tags: angular, primeng

I have a datatable with one column where the row data invokes a function in order to get the result to display. And i have noticed that whenever i mouseover the datatable, it seems it is rerendering since the function gets called once again for each row.

How can i disable this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While i didn't find out how to prevent this behavior, i decided to get the data from a static array instead of a method, this will at least avoid making multiple requests everytime i mouse over the datatable.